# Error ORA-00933 al usar query de oracle en python

Tags: python, oracle

Estoy armando un script en python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv

SQL="SELECT count(status) status FROM  v'$'session GROUP BY status"


# You can set these in system variables but just in case you didnt
os.putenv('ORACLE_HOME', '/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1')
os.putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('XXX/XXX:XXX/XXX')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
for row in cursor:
    print row
cursor.close()
connection.close()
FILE.close()
```

y me devuelve el error ORA-00933, diciendo que esta mal finalizada la query.

Comment: Bueno, ya lo pude solucionar, como dijeron abajo, era un tema de las comillas, no se porque antes me daba error igual, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En la línea donde generas el query solo hay que quitar los apostrofes donde seleccionas la tabla session

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import os
import cx_Oracle
import csv

SQL="SELECT count(status) status FROM  v$session GROUP BY status" ## Aquí esta el cambio


# You can set these in system variables but just in case you didnt
os.putenv('ORACLE_HOME', '/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1')
os.putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('XXX/XXX:XXX/XXX')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
for row in cursor:
    print row
cursor.close()
connection.close()
FILE.close()
```

[Aquí](https://gist.github.com/crmaxx/5507603) hay un query muy similar al tuyo sobre el cual te puedes basar